# Wordpress and Lazy load, I can't get it working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get lazy load js working in a wordpress site and can not for the life of me get it working. I tried the plugin's and while they work they lazy load all images and I can't have that happen on my homepage (long story, but it causes a jumping issue). I only want to lazy load images on specific pages. In the past I would simply link to the js file and add the class lazy to the images I wanted, but that obviously won't work. Here is what I tired...

**functions.php**

```
function load_lazyload() {
    wp_register_script( 'lazyload', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/jquery.lazyload.min.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'trigger_lazy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/lazy_trigger.js', array('jquery', 'lazyload'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'trigger_lazy' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_lazyload' );
```

Then added this to lazy_trigger.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    effect : "fadeIn"
});
```

});

Then I added the class lazy to the images I wanted to load.

No luck getting this to work. Can someone explain why or better yet explain a better way?

Comment: Have you tried using the console to see why its not working?  Do you have a live URL?

Comment: Currently no, everything is local.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [this jQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), you'll have to (a) specify a default image for the `src` attribute, and (b) add the url of the actual image to load as a html5 data attribute, e.g.:

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post ); 
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail', false, '' );
    $img = '<img class="lazy" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default.png" data-original="' . $src[0] . '" />';
    echo $img;
}
```

Comment: Sorry diggy, I'm not following. Where does that code go and for 'b' how would I load the url to the actual image? There are multiple posts with multiple images. Does that mean every image needs to be hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a wordpress Lazy Load Plugin which installs easily - just search lazy load in the plugins section.

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented in the following way:

```
add_filter( 'save_post', 'add_lazy_load', 10, 3 ); 
function add_lazy_load($post_id, $post, $update) 
{ 
if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
 { 
return; 
} 
if ( ! class_exists( 'DOMDocument', false ) ) 
return; 
remove_action('save_post', 'add_lazy_load'); 
$post_status = get_post_status(); 
if ($post_status != 'draft') 
{ 
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($post->post_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')); $images = $document-getElementsByTagName('img'); 
foreach ($images as $image) 
{ 
$image->getAttribute('load'); 
if (!$image->getAttribute('loading') || $image->getAttribute('loading') != 'lazy') 
{ 
$image->setAttribute('loading', 'lazy');
 } 
}
$iframes = $document->getElementsByTagName('iframe'); 
foreach ($iframes as $iframe) 
{ 
$iframe->getAttribute('load'); 
if (!$iframe->getAttribute('loading') || $iframe->getAttribute('loading') != 'lazy') 
{ 
$iframe->setAttribute('loading', 'lazy'); 
} 
} 
$html = $document-saveHTML(); 
wp_update_post(array( "ID" = $post_id, "post_content" => html_entity_decode($html), )); 
} 
add_action('save_post', 'add_lazy_load', 10, 3); 
}
```

Read more: https://www.plerdy.com/blog/lazy-loading-setup-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I just implemented.
Include this code into the functions.php target file where you JS is.

```
// lazy load
function lazy_load_scripts() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lazy_load', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lazyLoad.js');  
}
```

enqueue it on the desired page

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lazy_load_scripts' );
```

Give each of your divs where you want lazy load to happen class .lazy-load

this is a java script code

```
//  on scroll lazy load
 jQuery(window).scroll(function() {    
    let toEasyLoad = jQuery(".lazy-load img");
    toEasyLoad.each(function(element) {
        const top_of_element = jQuery(this).offset().top;
        const bottom_of_screen = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).innerHeight();

        //change this value if you want images to load much sooner than user comes to the div
        const offset = 100;    
            
        if ((bottom_of_screen + offset > top_of_element) && (jQuery(this).attr("data-src"))) {
            // the element is visible, do something                
                jQuery(this).attr("src", jQuery(this).data('src'));
                jQuery(this).removeAttr('data-src');                     
        }
    })    
});
```

Hope somebody will find it useful.